# Why some keywords in java start with capital characters and some of them start with small format of character?

Tags: java, syntax

why in java using String with capital case character but using int with small character?

```
String variable; 
int number;
```

Comment: `String` is not a keyword. And all keywords are lowercase

Comment: Primitive types are keywords and are lowercase. Class types are not keywords, and are uppercase.

Comment: so String is class?

Comment: It is. As is `Integer`, which is a class that boxes `int` if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `String` is a class, it is not a keyword.

`int` is a primitive type and a keyword hence in **lowercase**.

All **keywords** in java are in **lowercase**.

for your reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords